# Is there way to disable generation of "deps = gcc" in cmake with ninja generator?

Tags: c++, build, cmake, compiler-errors, ninja

I have a project in which files are compiled by the clang using the cmake with ninja generator. 
When building the application, I get a lot of warnings like these:

```
clang++: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-MD' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang++: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-MT CMakeFiles/{source}.o' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang++: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-MF CMakeFiles/{source}.o.d' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

I found out that the source of these warnings is [the optimizing feature](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html#_deps) of the ninja generator. I didn't find a way to disable its generation. Could someone please tell me if it exists? Also, if there is another way to make the compiler not write these warnings without turning off the -Wunused-command-line-argument option, I would appreciate it if someone would inform me about this.

Comment: I suspect you see these warnings because you pass these flags to the linker (`CMAKE_*_LINKER_FLAGS`).